# Why can you call toString() on an integer variable but not a literal number?

Tags: javascript

How come this works:

```
var num = 1;
console.log(num.toString()); // "1"
```

But this does not?

```
console.log(1.toString()); // SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Comment: You can do it this way - (1).toString()
Its sort of syntax rule with js, same with css for example, where your id/classname can't start with number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the grammar expects a `.` after a number to be parsed as part of that number, as it would be for e.g. `1.5`. You need to disambiguate the `.` if you want to use it as a member operator on a numeric literal:

```
1..toString();  // "1"
1.0.toString(); // "1"
(1).toString(); // "1"
```

In the first two cases the first `.` is parsed as a floating point. The second can only be parsed as a member operator because numeric literals can only contain a single floating point.

This is shown by the [*NumericLiteral* grammar](https://es5.github.io/#x7.8.3) in the spec.